# Where are these volcanos as seen in this space tweet?

Tags: geology, volcanology

In his recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/Astro_Feustel/status/1031535460655554560) from the International Space Station as it's current [Mission 56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_56) Commander, NASA astronaut [Andrew J. Feustel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_J._Feustel) says:

> This is #Indonesia as viewed from the @Space_Station. With the low clouds it is easy to see the peaks of the volcanoes associated with the Sunda Megathrust subduction zone that lies at the tectonic boundary of the Indo-Australian and Eurasian plates.

I can't visualize where these are on Earth, mostly because of the cloud cover in the image. Where is this?

[image: Indonesian Volcanos from Space]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was taken looking from around above or near Western Australia, looking north. You can see a fuzzy green patch to the centre and left of the photo. That's the eastern part of Java.

Here's the image where I labelled some of the volcanoes, and a reference image from Google Earth.

[image: original labelled]

[image: google earth]

Comment: By the way, the one that I didn't label but would be 8 if I did, is Mt Agung in Bali, which is a currently active volcano.

Comment: Then it needs a cartoon-like eruption rather than a green number!

Comment: Funny. I used the same colour, but it looks blue in the first image and green in the second. lol

Comment: I guess it's the same color, but with different backgrounds, and a little bit of mixing due to the thin lines, it looks different. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhde2.jpg